# Rapid closing of java.lang.NullPointerException questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question is *mainly* for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag crowd.

I've seen many NPE questions quickly closed as duplicate (often by diamond bearers), directing the user to [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)  This post addresses **what** and **how** of the topic with enough detail.

There is, however, one more question: **why**.  Why the ... is `null` in the first place?  For that one usually need to look for more errors either in syntax (complilable nevertheless) or in the program logic. Shouldn't we provide additional guidance and (if available) pick a duplicate closely resembling OP's particular case?

What is the community opinion: should we help OPs to nail down the **why** part or is it enough to point out to the general information and let them sweat out their specific solutions?

Comment: That is something the OP has to find out, they forever forget to include any hints and only focus on the exception.  There are an infinite possible *whys*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because there are dozens of these a day, so many that it can completely dominate the good questions.  Also, the vast majority of them don't show any research effort at all-  the vast majority are "what does this mean/why isn't this working" not "Hey I'm getting a null pointer exactly here and can't figure out why its null".  The second type is ok (although generally a stupid mistake rather than an interesting question).  The first type lowers the value of stack overflow.  And generally that second type can be reworded into a question that won't get closed.

By the way, you aren't wrong to do additional guidance-  I have two NPEs I typically refer to on Android, as 1 is a very specific very common one (a findViewById failure, which is typically asked every hour or more).  But its such a common question that if the didn't put in the time to search and find it, its not reasonable to expect me to do so for them.

Answer (score 7):

In 99% of the cases, a `NullPointerException` question is entirely uninteresting for anyone other than the OP. 
People who bother to research it find the canonical duplicate and can now find the problem on their own. People who don't bother to research are the ones that create these posts which have no value.

If someone knows what an NPE means then they can find out themselves what causes it. If they don't know, teach them by closing as a duplicate.

One remark I heard about this recently though is that people might not know how to debug. A canonical "how to debug" answer might be interesting to make for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah. Some of them know only about `System.out.println()` type of debugging.

Comment: @PM77-1 That's not the problem, as this kind of issue can easily be solved by that kind of debugging.  In fact I do more of that kind of debugging than any other-  debuggers are usually the wrong answer unless you're completely at a loss for what's going on.  The problem is they aren't putting in even that much effort.

Comment: @GabeSechan - I hear you about [*the effort*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216677/213957).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems