# Why was my PowerShell dupe-target question closed against one that I feel isn't as good?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I had a question regarding PowerShell and null pointer exception (NPE) handling, designed to be a "general" or (I've heard it called) "classic" answer, asked and self-answered some good seven years ago. It apparently attracted some linkage and attention and earned me some rep, so I feel it was at least decently formed.

This is the question I asked: *[You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression - general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335195/you-cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-valued-expression-general?noredirect=1)* -- it was closed as a duplicate of *[You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525170/you-cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-valued-expression)* originally.

Now out of the blue that question was closed as a duplicate, apparently by a golden badger in the [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag, against what I classify as a somewhat worse reference question. Since I'm not able to know who closed it, and the linked question had an actual example of code that caused an NPE right off the bat, instead of mine that tried to answer the question of "why my code SUDDENLY failed?" in a more general sense, I'm asking for clarification here.

Why was that question chosen instead of mine, why was the fact that my question is self-answered with (in my opinion) a decent explanation ignored, and why was the actual difference in questions ignored? The linked one had an uninitialized variable as the root cause, while mine described several possible root causes, with one of them being no data received, AKA an error in error handling in an otherwise correct script.

NPEs naturally can have several causes, so I think it’s incorrect to link all questions regarding NPE in PowerShell to an answer covering only a single cause (single instance of an uninitialized variable).

This meta question is related: [Rapid closing of java.lang.NullPointerException questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283306/rapid-closing-of-java-lang-nullpointerexception-questions). It's about the same age as my original question, and yes the reasoning in there probably applied to this moment in time as well, but my question is about selecting which one is "better" suited to be a reference. The one chosen in Java looks like it has one of the better "classic" answers, while, at time of posting, there were no such answers for PowerShell (and there still may not be).

Comment: What's stopping you from: a) editing the other question, and b) flagging for your answer to be merged to the other question?

Comment: @SamuelLiew that question was about a particular piece of code, and the answer was about that piece of code as well. So I'm not breaking a question apart, otherwise it'll be as good as deleting it with its answer. I'm actually about to vote for reopen my question, and if succeeds, I'd close *that* one linking to mine, just to enforce the justice XD

Comment: "Why that question was chosen instead of mine" - I am not SME, but: 1. The other question has a **code**. 2. The other question has the **complete** error message (with location of the error line). 3. The other question has much more views and votes. "why the fact that my question is self-answered with IMHO a decent explanation was ignored" - Self-answering was never an indicator of quality. And the answer to the other question contains explanations as well. BTW, I found your answer to perfectly fit for the duplicate question, not sure why you have created a new question for that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well it was 7 years back... Likely there was an influx of NPE questions in Powershell back then, so I was at a loss to which question should I make an answer. I thought that making yet another but using a different title wording was the best action I could make, so I went that route.

Comment: It is somewhat incomprehensible near *"while there was"*. E.g., is a word missing?

Comment: @Vesper, also, you [can tag gold-tag user, who closed your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), in comments to that question (You'll need to manually spell their nick though). It could be faster to reach them this way.

Comment: What value does separating the more general, "canonical" answer from the question that's been used as a canonical for years bring? https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: [1] You haven't included a link to the alleged duplicate, and that was fine while your SO question was closed. But since it has been reopened your post here has become fairly meaningless because we have no way of properly evaluating your concern. Can you update your question here to include a link to that alleged duplicate? [2] It would be much better to link to your SO question (_"This is the question I asked..."_) at the start of your question here, rather than near than the end. It's frustrating to have to wade through four context free paragraphs before we get to the meat of the matter.

Comment: @skomisa I added the previous dupe target link to the MSE question and moved it closer to the top.

Answer (score 8):

- It was I who closed the question as a duplicate, and I went by age and popularity - which isn't always the right choice, but there are no hard and fast rules; see below.
- I did not realize that yours was a self-answered question, but I don't think that should necessarily factor into the decision as to whether to close it as a duplicate.
- I agree that both your question and your answer are better than the original and its accepted answer (FWIW, I had up-voted both your question and your answer before closing), and in hindsight I agree with you that the explicitly *general* angle of your question makes it the better candidate for staying open, in the sense that new answers can then be posted.

  - I see that the question has been reopened, albeit without reversing the duplicate linkage - I'm leaving that alone; there's at least a *comment* linking to your post (by someone who originally suggested making yours the "original", which is how I learned of your post).

---

**Some general thoughts on closing questions that are uncontroversially duplicates:**

- Perhaps most importantly: If they are to be considered duplicates, I don't think it matters (much) *which* one is labeled the duplicate:

  - I know that it's not uncommon to perceive a post that is closed as a duplicates as stigmatized, but I don't think this perception is warranted:

    - *Readers* of these posts likely don't care, and certainly when I am personally looking for a solution, coming upon a post labeled as a duplicate *that has answers*:

      - (a) does *not* discourage me from reading the answers (which *may* be better than those for the linked post)
      - (b) merely tells me that *additional* information may be available in the answers to the linked post.
  - What matters at the end of the day is that these posts are *linked* and that users finding differently worded but in essence identical questions have access to *all* answers that may be relevant.
  - However, there *is* an asymmetry that I hadn't fully considered before: While for the *duplicate* the linked "original" is very prominently displayed, the "original" shows the linked duplicate relative unobtrusively in the right sidebar under "Linked" and can be buried among *other* linked posts that aren't actually duplicates but link to the "original" for different reasons.

    - I don't know what the order is, but duplicates are *not* necessarily on top, and also aren't marked as such.
    - I see that this has been discussed before; e.g.: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397609/45375
- From that vantage point, a question that has been closed as a duplicate *and has answers* arguably offers an *advantage* to future readers:

  - It offers them the answers at hand...
  - ... and also makes it *obvious* where to find at least *potentially* additional, relevant information (as opposed to having to sift through the "Linked" list, with no obvious up-front indication as to which linked post is *incidentally* linked or not).
- I think the solution lies in making duplicates quasi *peers* in terms of the end-user experience, which would put an end to the recurring debates about which is the "original" and which the perceived-as-stigmatized duplicate.

  - However, in the current model there is still an effective "loser" in that the closed-as-duplicate post can't accept new answers.
  - Perhaps the solution lies in loosening the concept of a duplicate to closely-related-and-in-essence-the-same-but-with-incidental-variations-that-may-matter-to-some, and allowing *all* posts linked in this way to stay open: this allows for new answers tailored to the specific angle, while prominently offering other posts that may have additionally relevant information.
  - Of course, this risks fragmentation of relevant information, but perhaps rules around when such linkage is permitted would help, such as based on the number of votes on the question.

Comment: `making duplicates quasi peers` Not sure if you've heard of merging, but mods can move all the answers from one post to another duplicate post. A flag by a gold badge, usually will be accepted.

Comment: "I know that it's not uncommon to perceive a post that is closed as a duplicates as stigmatized, but I don't think this perception is warranted".  That perception is definitely warranted - the message basically says this question is a duplicate of this better one, go and read the other one instead .....

Comment: @deep64blue, I encourage you to replace "better one" with "another one", otherwise you may miss valuable answers. However, the current wording could be improved from "This question already has answers here:" to (emphasis added) "This question _also_ has answers here:"  IF the question received answers before it was closed, so as to discourage the "better one" interpretation. Even if we assume that the question with the "better" answers is consistently chosen as the "original", it is the subjective judgment of the few close voters / the single gold-badge holder, and shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: @mklement0 I think you are missing the point - the whole system encourages you to think of duplicate answers as bad and my interpretation is what most people will come to I reckon.

Comment: @deep64blue, you are part of that system and your interpretation is part of the problem; this answer contains suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

For me, your question is well a duplicate of the other. It's the same issue for the same language.

1. **Your answer is better**

As @mklement0 said, yes your answer is better. It more explain the code, but the other answer is also pretty fine. Both are good. It means both should be kept.

2. **Your question is worst**

- If someone ask this question, it will be closed as need more focus or needs clarity.
- No code, no error log. Nothing to help the reader to think "yes I have the same issue"
- I see that in comment, you are thinking that thanks to it's a self-answered post, it could be the "rally point". But IMHO it should not be take in count to know which one is better, or should be the duplicate of others. A bad post which is self-answer stay a bad post. You're one is globally less useful than others for readers.

3. Others details

The other question has lot of views & upvotes. It's seems fine, useful and used. It help to think the other post is preferable to be used a the main one: more people already know it, like it and visit it. (Also, it could be more referenced so easier too find than you're one).

**To conclude**, I think **your answer should be merged to the other question** and your question be closed.

Answer (score -11):

Your question was closed because a subject matter expert determined it was a duplicate. How you, personally, *feel* about the closure is irrelevant, unless the closer asked you somewhere for your thoughts on that matter beforehand. Closure is based on content, not feelings.

Bear in mind that duplicate closure typically takes into account not just the age of a question but also the score and activity, the number of (and quality of) answers, the SEO value of the question body and title, and the general quality of the question. Older questions *do* get closed as duplicates of newer questions all the time due to these criteria. In this case, the question you asked isn't even older, so *none* of those criteria for not closing your question as a duplicate are met, in my opinion.

Comment: *"How you, personally, feel about the closure is irrelevant"* This feels "wrong". If the OP feels that their question *isn't* duplicate then that is relevant; they just need to ensure that they suitably demonstrate that it isn't a duplicate by editing the question and sending it to the review queue that the other users can see if they agree. One would hope, as well, that if they ping the gold badger and have suitably evidenced it's not a duplicate then the hammerer will reopen it. Questions aren't closed as duplicates and then left to never be reviewed.

Comment: @ThomA i mean, that's kinda the point. it doesn't matter how one feels about it, they need to show.

Comment: If someone says to me that it doesn't matter how I feel, @KevinB , they are telling me that no matter what I say or do things aren't going to change. That is not true with duplicates.

Comment: *there are really no criteria*  You seem to list some criteria before, like score activity, etc. But then you say there is "no criteria". Is the duplicate target better than the source or not and does the target adequately represent(/related to) the source? That is what OP of this post is discussing. Whether they're the OP of the original question or not is not material to judging the validity of the closure.  Your answer seems use a strawman about the "age of questions" and successfully crucified the strawman.

Comment: If the OP wrote a self-answered canonical question, it would seem likely that they are a subject matter expert as well.

Comment: @ThomA i think you're still confusing feelings with facts. I don't really care if someone *feels* they have a unique problem to solve, but if they provide enough information to prove it, I'd happily reopen it.

Comment: Why would someone try to prove something isn't a Duplicate if they don't feel it isn't, @KevinB . Feelings are relevant because you wouldn't try to do thing without the feeling.

Comment: @ThomA Fair, however, feelings alone aren't enough to justify reopening a question.

Comment: And I never said that was the case, @KevinB ; I explicitly stated that they will "need to ensure that they suitably demonstrate that it isn't a duplicate by editing the question".

Comment: @ThomA "*this feels "wrong"*" To be clear, you can disagree with closure, that's certainly your right. The system affords you the ability to cast a reopen vote on a question (including your own) starting at 3,000 reputation (before that, you can still put the question in the reopen vote review queue by casting a reopen flag or editing the question substantially). And if you own a gold badge in one of the tags used on the question, you can _unilaterally_ reopen duplicate questions (even your own). But it's important to note, as Kevin B mentioned, that _feelings_ are irrelevant.

Comment: @ThomA '*If someone says to me that it doesn't matter how I feel, KevinB , they are telling me that no matter what I say or do things aren't going to change. That is not true with duplicates.*" No, they are telling you that your _feelings_ don't matter. What you _say_ or _do_ are distinct/different from what you _feel_. Feelings are personal and opinionated. If you believe the question is not a duplicate or that it was incorrectly closed for some reason, then you should be able to provide objective reasons for consideration regarding reopening.

Comment: For example: "this is not a duplicate of question X. Question X is about Y and Z, whereas my question is about A". Or, "the questions are the same but mine is more general/is a better catch-all question for people encountering this error in various scenarios. I believe that question should be closed as a duplicate of mine instead.". Just saying "this question isn't as good as mine" is vague and doesn't even specify _in what way_ you think the question is not as good, so it's too opinionated to act on.

Comment: @TheMaster I was referring to the criteria I set forth above, not that there were no criteria at all by which to make a determination. I edited the phrasing to clarify what I was talkign about.

Comment: @Bergi That's certainly possible; I did not check. Although in my post I meant specifically someone with a gold badge in the relevant tag, not just a general domain expert, knowledge-wise. That being said, writing a self-answered Q&A is no guarantee of quality or expertise (and, in some cases, neither is having a gold badge, sadly). I have not examined the questions at stake here so I can't say whether the question was ultimately closed correctly or not, only that it appears to be the same question about the same error message and that it was posted _after_ the duplicate target that was chosen

Comment: @TylerH People don't like it and are downvoting accordingly. Perhaps take a hint that your language selection may be getting in the way of the point you are trying to make. An edit is likely warranted.

Comment: That people have disagreed with the answer, doesn't make it incorrect, ;)